# Spring: How do I dynamically set maximum amount of concurrent sessions

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Let's say I have app with several account types and each type has its own allowed maximum of concurrent sessions. For example, if the maximum is 1 then when user tries to log in from his laptop while being logged in on his desktop PC he should get an error.
How can I achive that with `Spring`? I know about `concurrency-control` but as far as I know it allows to "statically" set the limit for entire context.
I was thinking about `SpEL` but didn't came up with anything.

**P.S.**
Also I would like to know is there a specific exception being thrown when user exceeds the limit so I could handle it and show page with explanation why he can't log in.

**UPD**
Thanks to @Nándor for clever thoughts: when user tries to log in on another device he should be asked to either logout on the current device or on the other.

**UPD2**
I found that there is a bean of class [`SessionRegistry`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/session/SessionRegistry.html) and it holds all the neccessery information, also it allows to manually expire sessions. Also I can control amount of sessions with it.
**But** there's still problem remaining: how do I notify another device that session has been shut down? When I manually expire the session with `SessionInformation.expireNow()` it give me a page with following text on it:

```
This session has been expired (possibly due to multiple concurrent logins being attempted as the same user).
```

The text means exactly what I want but I'd like to handle this as I want. I tried `@ExceptionHandler` on `java.lang.Exception` but it hasn't catched anything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to deny log in from a new location because he's already logged in from another one. Imagine the situation, when he moves to a new location without logging out first, he won't be able to log in. A better idea maybe, to forcibly log him off from the other location (destroying his session) when logging in from a new one. If you agree, maybe it's worth closing your question and opening a new one before too many people jump on answering. If you still think that your question is what you want to achieve, please state so.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, that makes sense. But I realized a better way: if user forgot to log out, when he tries to log in on another device he will be asked to either logout on the current device or on the other. Can I achive that?

Comment: Definitely. I've seen it implemented in some web applications, don't remember their names though.

Comment: Please see the update, thanks for taking time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks [@Nándor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2699901/n%C3%A1ndor-el%C5%91d-fekete) for thoughts, I finally found a solution.

#### As to managing number of active sessions:

I use [`SessionRegistry`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/session/SessionRegistry.html) bean, it can manage active sessions on all principals. Also, I think it's worth mentioning that `SessionRegistry` appears to be empty until I took off the security configuration from servlet config to `applicationContext.xml`. Spring logs that it successfully put session id to the registry but its still empty unless it's declared in the `applicationContext.xml`.

#### As to handle session expiring:

`concurrency-control` tag has `expire-url` tag that holds url to which user will be redirected in case of expired session. I can map controller to it and do what I want.